# If it is possible to debug PHP of the admin side in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, admin, debug, phpstorm, xdebug

**General question**

Just interesting, if it is possible to debug the admin side in Manento2. If it is, wold be glad to saw some hints.

**Debug process now**

For now I'm using *PhpStorm* with *XDebug*. If I want to debug some module, I'm just setting breakpoints and run in debug mode "*Php Web Application*" preset with link to this module. I suppose this approach can't be used to debug the admin side because of some "key" dynamically generating all the time.

[image: desc]

Comment: Which is your OS?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh thank you for participation. macOS El Captain, but I have already received the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to debug the admin side.

Simplest way for you, it disables the secure key.

But you also can use chrome xdebug helper or [marklet](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/)  to start debug from any page. In this key better to configure "php remote debug".

PS: don't use Magento on "localhost", you will have problem with cookies. Add doment to host files (like mage.dev) and use it

Comment: For assistance with Composer, first [install Composer](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html#instgde-prereq-compose-install). Then use [this command line](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html#integrator-first-composer-ce) to get the software and finally install using either the [Setup Wizard](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/web/install-web.html) or [command line](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli.html).